# Changing port number in easyphp devserver 17

Tags: numbers, port, easyphp

I am using EasyPHP Devserver 17. I want to change it port number to 127.0.0.1:786. Because my all application has set to this type only. This new installation has default only 4 port 8080,8000,8008,8888. when ever I am trying to do manually it always reset back to normal. I am not able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

- Open the file `eds-app-dashboard.php` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apachexxx`
- Line 18, add your port number :

  $ports = array(786,80,8080,8000,8888,8008);