# Can EasyPHP Devserver Appache Listen to Multiple Ports?

Tags: apache, port, easyphp, devserver, easyphp-devserver

Installed EasyPHP Devserver on Windows 7.

> EasyPHP Devserver Version 17.0 (pretty the latest)
>
> EasyPHP Devserver Apache Version 2.4.25

***You may skip direct to my conclusion below.***

***Here is my process of trials.***

In the `httpd.conf` file, I added the second Listen port

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Then at the EasyPHP Devserver website console (http://127.0.0.1:1111) I restart the Apache. the `httpd.conf` file will be rewritten to the following, and Apache cannot start. (Where can I see the error log? Nothing written into EasyPHP Devserver\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache...\logs)

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

If I leave the `httpd.conf` file with only one Listen port

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Apache starts successful, but `httpd.conf` is also rewritten back to

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

And in the EasyPHP Devserver website console (http://127.0.0.1:1111) > Http Server Settings (the gear icon) > there is a drop down menu for us to select the Port: 80.

There are a few options, 80 8080, 8000, 8888, 8008. If I change here, and restart the Apache. the `httpd.conf` is updated according to this setting.

***Conclusion***

My conclusion is, no matter what I set in the `httpd.conf` file, the `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` will be rewritten by the setting in the EasyPHP Devserver website console > Http Server Settings > Port. The real setting is controlled by the EasyPHP Devserver website console. The `httpd.conf` file `Listen` directive is not functionable.

***Question***

Here comes the question. In fact I only wish to configure Apache Listens to multiple port, 80 for production and 8080 for development. How can I do it?

Comment: I wonder should EasyPHP questions goes into stackoverflow? I guess serverfault might be more appropriate, but serverfault even lack the EasyPHP tag. And how about superuser? In superuser, there is EasyPHP tag but no EasyPHP-Devserver tag. Hmm... I think I will just leave this in stackoverflow. Should you have better suggestions, please kindly let me know. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688508/changing-port-number-in-easyphp-devserver-17 Similar question here. But I still lack a method to make port setting multiple. I guess this might be the crap of EasyPHP ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Nice. I find out a Brute-Force solution.

In `EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache...\eds-app-actions.php` line 97, it is replacing the website console settings to the Apache httpd.conf. I just commented `// file_put_contents (__DIR__ . '\conf\httpd.conf', $serverconffile);` and Apache httpd.conf will not be overwritten anymore. Nice.

*See? The is one of the best parts of open-source. We can always Brute-Force it.*

Comment: Yet I have to admit this is a Brute-Force solution. I am still waiting for your nicer solution. May be specifying the settings in another .conf file?

Answer (score 0):

you have to comment line 66,67:

```
//$replacement = '${1}' . $server_port;
//$serverconffile = preg_replace('/^([\s|\t]*Listen.*\:[\s|\t]*)(.*)$/m', $replacement, $serverconffile);
```

the line update port number